# Winforms app not opening on a second computer where Visual Studio is not installed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have two computers. On the first, a MacBook Air, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014 Express. I am programming a WinForms app and later trying it on a second computer, a Sony. When I program only the WinForms features and try it in Sony, there is no problem. The WinForms  app is working perfectly.

But, when I program a database related WinForms app, the app is not working in the second computer (the Sony). There is no reaction when I click .exe file. SQL Server 2014 Express is installed on the Sony too, but Visual Studio is not.

I am using Linq to SQL class for connection with the `.mdf` file. Here is my simple example for testing:

```
readolny LtoSQLDataContext _db = new LtoSQLDataContext();
var all = _db.articles; // The table's name is article.
Radlabel1.Text = "<html>There are <b>" + all.Count() + "</b> articles in our database.";
```

Here is print screen image:

[image]

This code is not working in the second computer. Rather, the Winforms app is not opening when click the `.exe` file. Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No. The biggest problem is right here. I am clicking double to *.exe file. Wait cursor is shown a few seconds and later, the winforms app is not opened and no error is showing.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible for anyone to tell you what is wrong without looking at the code. Do you have empty catch-blocks anywhere that might swallow an exception?

Comment: You could add logging to a file in order to see what's going on, or you could try the classic approach of just adding some message boxes at various points in the code that say things like "got to LoadData function" etc. to help pinpoint where the app is failing.

If you're sure it's SQL, then some possible issues are:  database instance has a different name, database has a different name, user doesn't have permissions for the database etc.

Comment: Also, try wrapping your call to the datacontext in a try-catch loop and then just output the exception.ToString() to a message box.  That will tell you if it's a database issue and probably what the database issues is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use `try catch` block, I can catch the error. After this, I gave up using SQL Server. In my singled user project, I use SQLite. It is stunnigly good.